# Tensorflow: How to read records until the end of file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset for training an RNN, where sequences of samples are contained in individual files.

```
timeSeries1.bin
timeSeries2.bin
```

In each *timeseries.bin* is a varying number of samples. How can I load all the samples from one timeseries when the filenames exist in a *tf.train.string_input_producer*? I need to be able to discard the RNN state between sequences, which means I need to know when the end of a sequence has been reached.

This is my input pipeline function:

```
def input_pipeline(instructions, base_directory):

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(base_directory) if f.endswith('.bin')]

    filename_list = [os.path.join(base_directory, x) for x in files]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        filename_list, shuffle=True, capacity=100)
    example, label, feature_name_list = read_binary_format(filename_queue, instructions)

    num_preprocess_threads = 16
    capacity = 20

    example, label = tf.train.batch(
        [example, label],
        batch_size=700,
        capacity=capacity,
        num_threads=num_preprocess_threads)

    return example, label
```

I know I need to alter my batch size depending on the size of the file currently in the *filename_queue*, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Is it the batch size or the sequence length that is changing between files? What does read_binary_format return? The solution to your problem probably involves padding your sequences with zeroes though